# GIMP : Changing BG Color of a pretty complex image

Tags: images, gimp, image-editing

I want to replace the background color of a image [Attached below] with a lot of "stuff" in it. How will I go about doing this ?

I want to take out the white and replace it with Black.

[image]

Thanks In Advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can do it in many ways. 
Here below one:

- Open the image go on `color`, `color to alpha`; click.
- It opens a windows where should be just selected the white color.
  If the color selected is not the white one, click on the color and change it to `ffffff`.
- Now you have an image with a transparent background.
- On the left switch the background color to black. (you know if it is not black change the background color to black `000000`).
- Now you can select from menu `image` and `flatten image`.

`*** DONE ***`

[image]

Of course if you use another color instead of black you can see it better `:-)`

[image]

Comment: You are welcome, nonetheless on next time question try to elaborate a little more what you want to do... it will be more easy to answer you. `:-)`